# Forbidden message when serving a sinatra local site using nginx passenger

Tags: nginx, sinatra, passenger

I've followed the instructions for installing phusion passenger with nginx in ubuntu. I had some issues while installing since I use rvm and I had to install as root and the installer was failing to find rake so i temporarily chmoded /opt to be owned by my user and after installation I resetted ownership to root. I can see nginx welcome page but when I try to visit a sinatra app I get forbidden, the virtual host is pointed to the sinatra app public dir and the permissions for the whole app are 777.

Comment: What user is nginx running as?

Comment: I assume root since I start nginx with sudo /etc/init.d/nginx 
But I have not a user specified in the nginx config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my mistake was not using rvmsudo to install nginx with passenger, instructions here: http://rvm.io/integration/passenger/.

Answer (score 1):

Try Passenger 3. It automatically detects most permission problems and tells you how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a production system, you really don't need the flexibility of RVM as you should be using a single stable version of Ruby and Rails for Phusion.  Install the version you need, using Aptitude if that version is available, and be done with it.

Comment: It's a local machine. I want nginx with passenger for development.

Comment: Understood.  What does this gain you over running your sinatra web app directly from ruby, or using rackup?

Comment: Well, the app is allways available and you don't have to juggle with different ports if you are running several apps, is just more convinient.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the page that Google brought me to for my issue, which isn't a Passenger issue, but a Nginx reverse-proxy issue, you need to add the line

```
disable :protection
```

somewhere in your sinatra app. I have mine at the very end, outside any method (in global scope).

Comment: To address the downvote(s), yes, this is the stupid and insecure hack solution, but that should be pretty obvious from the code, particularly the "disable" and "protection" parts. But for anyone wondering why upgrading Sinatra to a more recent version broke it, it's because the earlier version didn't have this default protection to begin with.